# I need to replace some portion of my code automatically, among all files in a directory

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to convert a large website into PHP. All the files have almost similar head/header portion and footer section.

I'm trying to unify all these header section, and footer section by putting it into a seperate file.

So I need to replace all of my

1. header section (which spans anywhere from 1045 to 1535 lines) with

```php
<?php include_once "include/header.php" ?>
```

And

2. footer section (which spans anywhere from 80 to 140 lines) with

```php
<?php include_once "include/footer.php" ?>
```

from all the files in a directory..

This is a rough figure of what I need to do.. Please look the code below..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title></title>

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> <!-- Some Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> <!-- Some Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> <!-- Some Stylesheets -->

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src=""></script>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <nav class="nav1" role="navigation">
            <!-- Some HTML -->
        </nav>
        <div class="menubar1">
            <!-- Some HTML -->
        </div>
        <div class="menubar2">
            <!-- Some HTML -->
        </div>

        <!-- ========================================================= -->
        <!-- ========================================================= -->

        <!-- PAGE CONTENTS -->

        <!-- ========================================================= -->
        <!-- ========================================================= -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer class="site-footer">
            <!-- Some HTML -->
        </footer>

        <script src=""></script> <!-- Some Script Tags -->
        <script src=""></script> <!-- Some Script Tags -->
        <script src=""></script> <!-- Some Script Tags -->
        <script src=""></script> <!-- Some Script Tags -->

        <!-- Page -->

        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script>
            /* Some Scripts */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above given code, I need to replace everything from top to

```html
<div class="menubar2">
```

(Until it's closing Tag)
with

```php
<?php include_once "include/header.php" ?>
```

Also, I need to replace everything below footer

with

```php
<?php include_once "include/footer.php" ?>
```

Please help me replace that portion of the file with my string..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are those header/footer parts exactly the same in all files? In any case, you should be able to achieve this with mass regular expression replacement using an IDE/editor that has that capability. Your question is not specifically related to PHP though, unless you want to do it with a PHP script, which should also be possible.

Comment: No the header and footer aren't exactly the same in all the files.. That was one of the problems bugging me..

Comment: And yeah.. I need to do it with PHP.. I got to list and select all the file names in the folder, and extract their contents into a variable. But I could never figure out how to replace the lines..

Comment: Are those `<!-- ========================================================= -->` part of the actual HTML of your pages or not? Same for `<!-- PAGE CONTENTS -->`.

Comment: Hai.. Those comments are just for representation.. Actual code is way bigger than these.. I added those in the question so as to make it easier for others to read.

Comment: Sure, I asked cause it would've made the search pattern a tad more reliable. Anyway, I've answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that regular expressions should generally never be used with DOM. However, since we're talking mass replacing within files, I suppose this is acceptable in this case (you don't want to lose the formatting, and mass deleting nodes with DOM would be awkward as well).

Now, taking into account what you said in the other comment about the structure of your `menubar2` div, this should do it.

**Edit: now with dynamic number of divs under `menubar2`:**

```
// Compute the amount of divs within `menubar2` div
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$menubar2_inner_div_count = (new \DOMXPath($doc))
  ->query('//div[@class="menubar2"]//div')
  ->length;

// Header
$html = preg_replace(
  '/^.*?<div class="menubar2">' . str_repeat('.*?<\/div>', $menubar2_inner_div_count + 1) . '/s', 
  '<!-- Header -->' . PHP_EOL . '<?php include_once "include/header.php" ?>', 
   $html
);

// Footer
$html = preg_replace(
  '/<footer class="site-footer">.*?<\/html>/s', 
  '<?php include_once "include/footer.php" ?>', 
  $html
);

// (Optional) Remove now useless indentation (supposes your indent is 8 spaces, 
// otherwise replace accordingly)
$html = preg_replace('/^ {8}/m', '', $html);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/G3HbK**

Comment: @Jayakrishnan Any comment on this? You can see it working on the demo link above.

Comment: Hi, I already got it working, using similar code (Please refer the other question's comment).. What I need now, is something which does not involve counting the number of end tag in all the files.. Please help me if something like this is possible.

Comment: Hai.. Sorry for the very laaatee reply.. I got some busy with other projects, so this was on hold.. Thanks Again for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick rough fix... didn't test it but hope it works!

Quick heads up! If you are planning on adding `<div>` inside `<div class="menubar2"></div>` then add this `<div class="match-hidden"></div>` after `</div>` closing tag of `class .menubar2`.

Change first `preg_match` with 
`preg_match('/<!DOCTYPE html>(.*?)<div class="match-hidden">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file,$newfile);`

```
$file = file_get_contents('replace_head.html');
preg_match('/<!DOCTYPE html>(.*?)<div class="menubar2">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file,$newfile);
preg_match('/<footer class="site-footer">(.*?)<\/html>(.*?)/s',$file,$newfile2);
if($newfile == TRUE){
$file1 = str_replace([$newfile[0]],['<?php include_once "include/header.php" ?>'],$file);
if($newfile2 == TRUE){
$file2 = str_replace([$newfile2[0]],['<?php include_once "include/footer.php" ?>'],$file1);
//header('content-type:plain/text'); 
//Un-comment this if you want to download current file
header('content-type:application/json');
//Comment this if you want to see it as html
echo($file2);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. This almost did it..

Although the footer works perfectly, the header leaves final 2 div closing tags undetected..

This is how my "menubar2" is structured..

<div class="menubar2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

This is how I get the output after running the code you gave me..

<?php include_once "include/header.php" ?>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: I can't seem to format the code in comments section like I did in the question.. Hope you'll understand it..

Comment: Btw, I tried to recreate the problem with the footer section (By wrapping all the contents of footer section in 2 divs.. like <footer><div><div> --- </div></div></footer>). But it seems to work fine..

Comment: Just add `<div class="match-hidden"><div>` after  `<div class="menubar2"> <div> <div> <ul> <li></li> <li></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div>`  for preg_match to complete and use this `preg_match('/<!DOCTYPE html>(.*?)<div class="match-hidden">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file,$newfile);`

Comment: Hi I'm sry for asking things repeatedly. But editing the project files isn't practical as there's 100s of files in total.. If I was to add <div class="match-hidden"><div> in all those files, It'd take day's of work. I would rather include the header and footer php tags manually by the time I add the div you suggested. Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: I played a little around the preg_match you gave me, and it seems to work when I change it to preg_match('/<!DOCTYPE html>(.*?)<div class="menubar2">(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file,$newfile);

Comment: That is selecting closing `</div>` after the closing of `<div class="menubar2">` `</div>`

Comment: Although I got it working with that code, Is there some other way which doesn't involve counting the number of </div>'s inside <div class="menubar2"> ?